# Hearthstone on PlayOnLinux: I can ALT+TAB out of the game, but I can't ALT+TAB back in

Tags: 14.04, wine, playonlinux

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

I installed Hearthstone via PlayOnLinux and it works excellently. The only problem is that I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of Hearthstone to go to another application, but I can't <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back into Hearthstone. The game appears, but I can't click on anything in it as if it were still an inactive window.

To exit it, I end up having to kill it via the terminal.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please include terminal output and let us know what graphics you are using?

Comment: This is a known bug, and not specific to HearthStone, please try this : https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=20646#p92758